# Websocket communication in a symfony project

Tags: websocket, symfony

I want to send notification from server to browsers in a php symfony project.
Is there a simple way to do this in symfony ?

Comment: Symfony is a PHP backend framework. It does not support websocket connections. You will need some websocket proxy. This can be based on React PHP or Node.js due to the asyc requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past I tried to use the Wrench library, which has a Symfony bundle :

https://github.com/varspool/WebsocketBundle

This is a wrapper for the Wrench library, which allows you to create websocket applications.

It seems to be quite simple to configure :

```
# app/config/config.yml
varspool_websocket:
    servers:
        default: # Server name
            listen: ws://192.168.1.103:8000 # default: ws://localhost:8000

            # Applications this server will allow
            applications:
                - echo
                - multiplex

            # Origin control
            check_origin: true
            allow_origin: # default: just localhost (not useful!)
                - "example.com"
                - "development.localdomain"

            # Other defaults
            max_clients:             30
            max_connections_per_ip:  5
            max_requests_per_minute: 50
```

Then you declare your WS application as a service.

```
<!-- Application\ChatBundle\Resources\config\services.xml -->
<service id="chat_service" class="Application\ChatBundle\Services\ChatService">
    <tag name="varspool_websocket.application" key="chat" />
</service>
```

To install it, use composer :

```
composer require wrench/wrench
composer require varspool/websocket-bundle
```

The rest of the setup documentation is written on the repository !

I didn't try it, but perhaps there is your solution :)